# latin-square.js Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, callstack

I am trying to use latin-square library for node.js in a loop to find some pattern, run the script and after 2 minutes have this error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
var latinSquare = require("latinsquare");
var lookup;
var loop;
lookup    =    ls();

console.log("first: "+ lookup);

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function find() {
    lookup    =    ls();
    console.log("loop: " + lookup);
    if(codeM(000000) == "1558" && codeM(111111) == "8691"){
        console.log("find: " + lookup);
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
}

loop =    setInterval(find,500);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function ls(){
    var table = [];
    lookup = latinSquare.generate([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

    for(i=0;i<lookup.length;i++){
        for(d=0;d<lookup[i].length;d++){
            table.push(lookup[i][d]);
        }
    }
    return    table;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function codeM(data){
    // this function return a result of mathematic procces. not call another function.
}

function padLeft(nr, n, str){
    return Array(n-String(nr).length+1).join(str||'0')+nr;
}
```

Comment: cant edit question!

Comment: coment in first row "// this function return a result of mathematic procces. not call another function." its a mistake Let's pretend it does not exist

Comment: Is there some particular reason your code is double-spaced?

Comment: Change the variable name in your ls() function from lookup to something else and I think you'll find it goes away. lookup is defined as a global, and you are assigning it different values in each function, one of which recurses (latinSquare.generate())

Answer (score 0):

Well ... to look for a pattern in a mathematical function, I need this code below to work infinitely. I am a beginner in javascript and I do not know how to solve it

```
var latinSquare = require("latinsquare");
```

var count =0;

setInterval(function(){

```
var table =[];

var search  =   latinSquare.generate([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

for(i=0;i<search.length;i++){

    for(d=0;d<search[i].length;d++){

        table.push(search[i][d]);

    }
}

count++;
```

console.log(count + "...... " + table);

},100);

Comment: It is clear that in the code above there is nothing more than an infinite loop, there is no function to search or compare anything. But that is the code that I want it to work and then I add the comparison function